How to add TV icon for a flutter android application
I recently created an application in Flutter, everything is looks fine in the phone but in the TV version there is no Icon in home ( banner) to start the application. application has been installed and available to run via >settings> apps.
but I want to add it to the google andorid TV home page.
I search a bit and I found this document in native andorid development.

There are two icon types for Android TV OS apps in AndroidManifest.xml:
android:icon (standard, mandatory)
android:banner (banner, mandatory)
Adaptive icons are highly recommended.
Both the icon and banner must comply with the design guidelines outlined in this guide.
Use the official figma template for generating the banner & icons
Android TV OS doesn't support themed icons.

I'm using mipmap for creating icon,
I tried the following manifest config but didn't work.
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:label="yfplayer"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:banner="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

Icon in ok both in Phone and TV, but there is no TV home banner.
what could the solution for that?

The specifications for a banner differ from those for a launcher icon. Have you tried creating a dedicated banner mipmap that has the specified aspect ratio?

@CommonsWare I haven't because I thought the mipmap generate icon in all different resolution. that a valid ponit to test. :)

@CommonsWare do we have a sample for that?
